# Subtract columns from two tables after grouping (for inventory)

Tags: php, mysql

So for my inventory system I have two tables with the same columns names (one for stock produced and one for stock shipped). I figured out how to group the columns by the product and then sum the quantities. So I want to run this query on both tables then subtract the quantity column from each table where the product variables match up.

I use this to add group and sum stock totals (in):

```
 $query = "SELECT id, type, color, product, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity FROM inventory GROUP BY id, color, type";
```

And I use this to group and sum stock shipments (out):

```
$query = "SELECT id, type, color, product, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity FROM shipped GROUP BY id, color, type";
```

So how do I subtract the quantity columns for each of these?

**Edit:**

I use this for output: (a table)

```
 echo '<tr><td>'. $row['product'] . '</td><td id="replace">' . $row['type'] . '</td><td>' . $row['color']. '</td><td>'. $row['TotalQuantity'];
 echo "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: What code do you have besides the queries? Are you using PDO? If not, you should be.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I am very new to php and mysql so no I am not using PDO in fact I don't even know what that is... I will be googling now!

Comment: Can you provide some sample output of these queries? How many rows do they return? If there are multiple, how do you want them subtracted?

Comment: @mcflause i've start pdo with this tutorial it's simple and good http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Connecting-Use-PHP-Data-Object-P546.html

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I updated the post to include the output

Answer (score 1):

This can be done entirely in one query. An `INNER JOIN` between these will allow you to subtract the quantities. The `id, color, product` columns are only needed from one of the tables in your `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT
  inv.id, 
  inv.color,
  inv.product,
  /* total inventory quantity */
  SUM(inv.Quantity) AS TotalInvQuantity,
  /* total shipped quantity */
  SUM(ship.Quantity) AS TotalShipQuantity,
  /* inventory quantity minus shipped quantity */
  SUM(inv.Quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(ship.Quantity), 0) AS SubtractedQuantity
FROM
  inventory inv
  LEFT JOIN shipped ship ON inv.id = ship.id AND inv.color = ship.color AND inv.product = ship.product
GROUP BY
  inv.id,
  inv.color,
  inv.product
```

#### Update after comments

```
SELECT
  inv.id,
  inv.color,
  inv.product,
  inv.TotalInvQuantity, 
  COALESCE(ship.TotalShipQuantity, 0) AS TotalShipQuantity,
  inv.TotalQuantity - COALESCE(ship.TotalQuantity, 0) AS SubtractedQuantity
FROM (
    SELECT id, product, color, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalInvQuantity
    FROM inventory
    GROUP BY id, product, color
  ) inv
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, product, color, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalShipQuantity
    FROM inventory
    GROUP BY id, product, color
  ) ship ON 
      inv.id = ship.id 
      AND inv.product = ship.product 
      AND inv.color = ship.color
```

Comment: This code is taking me in the right direction. The problem though is that only product that are in both tables are displayed. So for products that are only in the inventory table and not the shipped table they are not displayed

Comment: @mcflause That's easily fixed by using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, but also then need to account for NULL in `ship.Quantity` when subtracting.  Done via `COALESCE()`

Comment: I did some testing and there are some problems actually. First is that there is wierd subtracting going on from other products with the same ID but different color/type. And the shipquantity does add similiar rows before subtracting, it just uses one row for the product.

Comment: @mcflause Probably because more join conditions are needed. Added color and product to the `ON` clause.

Comment: the problem is that the code needs to get the grouped by values  for each table and then do the subtraction. With the current code you provided it gives incorrect values because it performs the minus function for each row in the table.

Comment: Wait, what does your id identify? Is it a row id (one per table), or a product id (many per table)?

Comment: @mcflause I didn't think it would be necessary to join subqueries, but perhaps it is. Try the addition above. Else I might have totally misunderstood your intent.

Comment: I decided to go a different way with the database design. I will be putting the stock and shipments rows all in the same table and assigning a tinyint to differentiate them (0,1). But I will test the code you provided soon to ensure it works and if so I will definitely accept the answer. Thanks.